# Cannot see Ubuntu partition in Windows disk mangement

Tags: uninstall, boot-partition

[There are no partitions for ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SslP.png)

Even though my system has Ubuntu installed, the disk management does not show ubuntu in them. I dont know any other way to uninstall ubuntu. Please help

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  The details you've provided conflict with each other and you haven't actually described any problem that is relevant to using Ubuntu.  You are saying simultaneously that Ubuntu is already installed and also that you don't know how to install Ubuntu.  You should edit your question and include more details. Disk Management in Windows really has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-in-a-windows-10-dual-boot-system/

Comment: Open Gnome-Disks in Ubuntu and note the size of the root partition. Delete the partition with the same size using WDM. Better yet boot the computer with a Ubuntu Live USB and delete the Ubuntu partitions from there.